# Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 3:0 missing ALL at 'select' near '' line 5:0 missing ALL at 'select' near ''

Tags: sql, impala

I am running the following query in Impala

```
select count(id) from (select s_id as id, m_id from hur_e_s_amer
union
select s_id, m_id from hur_e_s_emea
union
select r_id, m_id from hur_e_r_amer
union
select r_id, m_id from hur_e_r_emea
) t1
join (select m_id, d_date from hur_e_c_amer
union
select m_id, d_date from hur_e_c_emea
where d_date between '2018-04-09 00:00:00.0' and '2018-06-08 23:59:59.9'
) t2
on t1.m_id = t2.m_id
```

and then I am getting the following error

> Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 3:0
>   missing ALL at 'select' near '' line 5:0 missing ALL at 'select' near
>   ''

The strange thing is I am sure this query was working correctly before but it now doesnt seem to want to work any more.

Any ideas?

Comment: That's valid ANSI SQL syntax.

Comment: Does it matter that I am using Impala? Also, if not, what is wrong with it?

Comment: What has changed that it was working before but not anymore?

Comment: Nothing that I am aware of. That's the strange thins. It was a query I had saved that I have come back to run again and now I get that error. I could be sure it worked previously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem occurred because I was trying to run the query in the Hive editor, not the Impala one.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason I cannot replicate the error. Most probably because we are not using the Impala version (it would be always useful add it for this kind of quesitons). My best guess is because you are not adding aliases to the columns during the query to match the schemas between the selects. can you try this ?

```
select count(t1.id) from (select s_id as id, m_id from hur_e_s_amer
union
select s_id as id, m_id from hur_e_s_emea
union
select r_id as id, m_id from hur_e_r_amer
union
select r_id as id, m_id from hur_e_r_emea
) t1
join (select m_id, d_date from hur_e_c_amer
union
select m_id, d_date from hur_e_c_emea
where d_date between '2018-04-09 00:00:00.0' and '2018-06-08 23:59:59.9'
) t2
on t1.m_id = t2.m_id
```

Comment: @Taylrl, added the aliases for s *brid as id

Comment: I see. Unfortunately this didn't change anything.

Comment: impala version ?

Comment: Bingo! I was using the Hive editor rather than the Impala one. Thanks!